# made $_SESSION[] data into php variable but it still won't work in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have trouble with checking a $_SESSION variable on a mysql query. What I want to do is get the details of the User logged in, but it appears that it is not working properly.

I have `$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);` which puts the code into a regular variable, and then I make the query to the 
database which is:`$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1";`

and to count if the user exists I use the code: `$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount`

This does not seem to work. I keep getting this error: "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/alexartl/public_html/CRM/headercode.php on line 18"

And By the way, the user account does exist and is logged in when I have been testing this
Below is the full code

```
  // If the session vars aren't set, try to set them with a cookie
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];   
    }
  }
?>
<?php
//if the username is set
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
//making the username into a php variable 
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
//the query to grab the users name
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1";
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
        if ($userCount == 1) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
//just the array that grabs all the users info
            $username = $row["username"];
            $password = $row["password"];
            $first_name = $row["first_name"];
            $last_name = $row["last_name"];
            $gender = $row["gender"];
            $birthdate = $row["birthdate"];
            $email_address = $row["email_address"];
            $city = $row["city"];
            $state = $row["state"];
            $retrieval = $row["retrieval"];
            $isAdmin = $row["isAdmin"];
            $join_date = $row["join_date"];


//if the user has "isAdmin" as "Yes", then this link to a "manage Users" page will appear
            if($isAdmin == "Yes"){
                $ifAdmin = '<li><a href="manageUsers.php">Manage Users</a></li>';
                }
            }       
        }
     }      
?>
```

Comment: First you have to mysql_query($sql) to be able to count the rows :)

Comment: FYI, `$_SESSION` behaves like a regular array.

Comment: thanks @Alex! That indeed was the problem, things are working now and I couldn't be happier!

Comment: thanks, @ÁlvaroG.Vicario for the insight. I am still new to php and any new piece of information is valuable to me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't get into the "Don't use mysql_* commands", but don't :P

You are missing:

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql);  //Actually execute the query
```

Then use as

```
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($result); // count the output amount
```

---

Separately, you also don't seem to connect to, or `use` the database you wish to query.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect to mysql server.' );
mysql_select_db('databaseName');
```

Comment: Haha well said; that first line :) +1

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Oh and I totally accidentally left that part of code out on my question. I did use a include"" to connect to my database, SO good, can't believe I forgot to add the "mysql_query part"

Comment: No bother. Don't forget to accept (click the little green tick) and optionally upvote (the little up arrow next to the question) the answer that helped.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for your input I really appreciate it. All these answers have helped me so much, I tried your solution first and it worked. And yeah, I forgot to add in the code where I connect to the database in my question. but still, good to see you pick up on that!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have to execute the query and pass that query parameter to `mysql_num_rows()`. Find below,

```
$sql       = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1";
$qry       = mysql_query($sql);
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($qry);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){

 }
```

**Note : Please do not use mysql functions. They are deprecated. So, move to PDO (or) mysqli functions.**

Comment: haha, yeah thanks so much. I did actually begin learning using myslqi_

but I followed a tutorial online that I guess gave me some bad habbits haha

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1";
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

You have to first execute this query and then give that result to `mysql_num_rows`. Not just the query string

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**Disclaimer** : Hate to suggest a solution involving the use of `mysql_*` functions, but that's what your error is

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for you input I really appreciate it. All these answers have helped me so much. (and also has taught me to use mysqli_ instead from now on, haha

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using deprecated functions?

```
$oConnection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
$oStatement = $oConnection->prepare($sQuery);
$oStatement->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$row = $oStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You will not need to worry about escaping, you got clean and actual code.

Also instead of

```
        $username = $row["username"];
        $password = $row["password"];
        $first_name = $row["first_name"];
        $last_name = $row["last_name"];
        $gender = $row["gender"];
        $birthdate = $row["birthdate"];
        $email_address = $row["email_address"];
        $city = $row["city"];
        $state = $row["state"];
        $retrieval = $row["retrieval"];
        $isAdmin = $row["isAdmin"];
        $join_date = $row["join_date"];
```

you can just use extract function() instead http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php - much less to write ;)

Comment: Oh thanks! I never used the extract function, thanks for the info!